# Syntax error on CASE Statement join in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the below query and subquery where I am getting a `SUM` value, and I want to join `PS_VOUCHER_LINE LineSub` conditionally (on Line.LINE_NBR = LineSub.LINE_NBR) on `PS_VOUCHER Line` only when a `VOUCHER_ID`  has more than 1 `LINE_NBR`, otherwise I don't want this last join condition to execute. I am getting a Syntax error on the statement (*Incorrect syntax near '='.*) . How can I get this conditional join to work properly?

```
SELECT  
    CONCAT(Header.BUSINESS_UNIT, Header.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID 
    ,   
        ( 
        
            SELECT SUM(LineSub.MERCHANDISE_AMT) 
            FROM PS_VOUCHER_LINE LineSub
            WHERE Line.BUSINESS_UNIT = LineSub.BUSINESS_UNIT 
            AND Line.VOUCHER_ID = LineSub.VOUCHER_ID 
            AND 
                CASE 
                    WHEN COUNT(Line.LINE_NBR) > 1 THEN Line.LINE_NBR = LineSub.LINE_NBR
                END
            GROUP BY LineSub.VOUCHER_ID 
        ) + Header.FREIGHT_AMT + Header.SALETX_AMT AS GROSS_AMT_LINE_FREIGHT_TAX
FROM 
    PS_VOUCHER Header
    INNER JOIN PS_VOUCHER_LINE Line ON Line.BUSINESS_UNIT = Header.BUSINESS_UNIT 
        AND Line.VOUCHER_ID = Header.VOUCHER_ID
WHERE 
    Header.VOUCHER_ID = '00241107'
```

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.  There is so much wrong with this query that it is not worth trying to fix one error at a time.

Comment: I can't provide sample data because of the syntax error.

Comment: . . Sample data comes from the tables (or is made up) and has nothing to do with the syntax error.

Comment: CASE need ELSE condition

Comment: I tried the following changes for the `CASE` statement but I get an error about "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."  Could the below be modified to work at all?

`AND LineSub.LINE_NBR = CASE WHEN COUNT(LineSub.LINE_NBR) > 1 THEN Line.LINE_NBR ELSE LineSub.LINE_NBR END`

Comment: again. you dont need a case. case - when you have an options. in your situation just a condition. GROUP BY LineSub.VOUCHER_ID  HAVING  COUNT(Line.LINE_NBR) > 1

Answer (score 0):

just remove case and add add having where condition:

```
GROUP BY LineSub.VOUCHER_ID HAVING COUNT(Line.LINE_NBR) > 1
```

Comment: Uhh in this case the `ELSE` would need to be able to stop this join condition. I only want to join on `LINE_NBR` **if** the count of `LINE_NBR` for a `VOUCHER_ID` is greater then one. Otherwise then I don't want this join condition included. The 2nd suggestion also will not work because I have VOUCHER_ID's with just a count of 1 LINE_NBR, in addition to ones with more than a count of 1 LINE_NBR.

Comment: so if it would be null, it will not be used in parent condition... i think you don't need a case there.